# Foursquare API - Access foursquare token, when "connected app" uses facebook to login

Tags: facebook, api, foursquare

We are building a foursquare connected app, using Facebook for login. In this scenario, is there a way for our servers to see foursquare access token specific to our app, so that we can associate that token with the user account validated against facebook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to get a list of all access tokens for your app. When a user authorizes your app with Foursquare, you should store their OAuth access token so you can make requests on their behalf. You will follow a similar process to authenticate with Facebook. Your app will need to maintain the association between their Foursquare token and their Facebook token.

If you have lost the Foursquare access token, you can send the user to foursquare.com/oauth2/authenticate, as on this page (https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/auth), and your app will receive another OAuth token for the user, as you did when they originally authorized the app.